# php : xml node content edit and return xml

Tags: php, domdocument, ixmldomdocument

Here is my XML`<response>  <statusCode>200</statusCode>  <statusText>OK</statusText>  <data>    <getAssetResponse>      <assetId>89898</assetId>      <content>        some text with HTML content      </content>     </getAssetResponse>   </data></response>`

In my php, I need to replace content node substr (HTML with xhtml) and return the XML with same structure.

`<?php  $file = file_get_contents("filx.xml");  $doc   = DOMDocument::loadXML($file);  $data  = $dom->getElementsByTagName("data");  foreach($data as $node){echo "hello";}`

my simple start isn't working...What do i need to do to get the node content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to replace the content of the content-node, it is maybe easier to use SimpleXML, like this:

```
<?
$xml_object = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$xml_object->data->getAssetResponse->content = "Test 123";
print $xml_object->asXML();
?>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <response>
    <statusCode>200</statusCode>
    <statusText>OK</statusText>
    <data>
      <getAssetResponse>
        <assetId>89898</assetId>
        <content>Test 123</content>
      </getAssetResponse> 
    </data>
  </response>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's great. But I want to find & replace...So, I tried the following...<?php

$input = "file.xml";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($input);
$data-content = $xml->data->getAssetResponse->content;
$new-data = str_replace("NEW", "OLD", $data-content);
$xml_object->data->getAssetResponse->content  = $new-data;
print $xml_object->asXML();
?> is not working

Comment: That is weird.. The following code works perfect on my PC:
`<?
$xml_object = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$content = $xml_object->data->getAssetResponse->content;
$content = str_replace("Test", "TEST", $content );
$xml_object->data->getAssetResponse->content = $content;
print $xml_object->asXML();
?>`